# Swift - Own struct/class for current location (CLLocationManager)

Tags: xcode, swift, struct, location, cllocationmanager

I want to create an own struct or class that fetches the users current location.

It seems that I'm unable to use the CLLocationManager and it's functions (didUpdateLocations, didFailWithError, etc.) in a struct (Xcode makes all of the text color black and I get an error saying `An internal error occurred. Source editor is limited.`). When I use a class and try to use a "getPlacemark"-function (to get the placemark from the instanced class) or just get it directly from the instance created ("instancedClass.placemarkInClass"), but nothing works, I only get `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

This is my last attempt on creating a class:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class UserLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    var mLocationManager: CLLocationManager
    var placemark: CLPlacemark

    override init(){
        placemark = CLPlacemark()
        self.mLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.mLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.mLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.mLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                print("Error: " + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            if (placemarks?.count > 0) {
                let pm = placemarks![0]
                self.placemark = pm
                print(self.placemark.areasOfInterest)
                self.mLocationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            }

        })

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("Error: " + (error.localizedDescription))
    }

    func getPlacemark() -> CLPlacemark{
        return self.placemark
    }

}
```

In my ViewController I make it an instance variable ( *currentLocation = CurrentLocation()* ) and try to use both

> let userPlacemark = currentLocation.getPlacemark()
>   and
>   let userPlacemark = currentLocation.placemark
>   but nothing is working.

Is there a way to have an own class or struct to fetch the current location and use it in other ViewControllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two observations with your code:

1. You are not calling the [super init] in your init once you finish setting up the member variables. Modify you init as

   ```
        init(){

          placemark = CLPlacemark()

           mLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
           mLocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
           mLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
           mLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
           super.init()
           mLocationManager.delegate = self
          }
   ```
2. Setting up delegate of location manager. You should do this in init soon after you create instance of location manager. See the init code above.

Comment: When i use that I get _'self' used before super.init call_. But the problem is that I can't receive the location. When I try to use the getPlacemark method, the location isn't set. I've tried to use [OneShotLocationManager](https://github.com/icanzilb/OneShotLocationManager), but it isn't working. It's a class like that I want to create. I can't seem to find any tutorial or SO post that gives me the answer.